# How to reproduce "systemctl EDIT" behavior in Ubuntu LTS

Tags: services, startup-applications, systemd, etc

**Context:** I'm trying to configure DNScrypt. The instructions call the command:

```
sudo systemctl edit dnscrypt-proxy.socket
```

The **edit** command for `systemd` was introduced in version 218. Ubuntu LTS and Debian stable shipped with `systemd` version 215.

How do I mimic the behavior of the **edit** command manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Copy the file `/lib/systemd/dnscrypt-proxy.socket` to `/etc/systemd/system`.
2. Edit the parameters you wish to change.
3. Done.

This works because the system will preferentially use definitions found in `/etc/systemd/system` over `/lib/systemd/`.

We copy the default service definition from `/lib/systemd/` rather than creating a stub *edits.conf* , `/etc/systemd/system/dnscrypt-proxy.d/edits.conf` because systemd versions 217 and earlier do not support stubs.